# How handling a request with different mapping than model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm facing a problem for which I doesn't have found a solution : when I update an item I must update it to a second database where the model is different (example: the request send an input text 'title' and it must be recorded to the field 'intitule' in the second database).
In my fist database the request fit the model and there is no problem, but in the second, the update query does not happen.
I tried to change the set mutator without success.
Did you have experienced this problem and do you have solved it ?

Here is my Model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Old;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stage extends Model
{
    // Ce modèle est celui de l'ancienne base de donnée

    // changement de connexion
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    //la nom de la table ne correspond pas au nom par défaut attendu par le framework au regard de du nom du modèle
    protected $table = 'stages';
    //changement de clés primaire par défaut attendu par le framework
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_stages';

    // Ces champs ne sont pas modifiables
    //protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['intitule_stage'];

    //On ne remplit pas de champs created_at et updated_at par défaut ds Eloquent
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function setTitleAttribute($value){
        $this->attribute['intitule_stage']=$value;
    }

}
```

here is the controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Formation $formation)
    {
        //dd($request);
        $requestFormation = FormationRequest::createFrom($request);
        $requestStage = StageRequest::createFrom($request);

        //dd($requestFormation);
        $formation->update($requestFormation->all());
        $stage = Stage::findOrFail($formation->id);

        if ($this->updateStage($requestStage, $stage)) {
            session()->flash('success_message', 'Modification enregistrée');
            return redirect(route('formation.index'));
        }

    }

    private function updateStage(StageRequest $request,Stage $stage):bool {
        //dd($request->input('titre'));
        return $stage->update($request->all());
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What I see as a quick and easy solution is to put values from `$request` to new array.

```
$request->all()
```

will return an array. So you can take data that you need, put them to another array and push to update method.

```
private function updateStage(StageRequest $request,Stage $stage):bool 
{
      return $stage->update([
       'inititle' => $request->input('titre'),
        ...
      ]);
}
```

Comment: Ok but I loose the benefit of the FormRequest validation ?

Comment: No you will not, because validation is handling by controller. Controller only receive an array. Ordinary php array. It's up to you to decide where it is cumming from and what is inside.